# PowerMockito not creating Mock objects with whenNew

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am trying to mock new keyword in the constructor of my A class. I have written the tests for that but it is still calling the actual constructor of B when I call the constructor of A.

```java
class A {
public A()
{
  B b = new B(Config config);

}

}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
class ATest {
public void Test()
{
  B b = mock(B.class);            
  PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(b);
  A a = new A();
}

}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.

Comment: It is compiling but the issue is it is not mocking the constructor of B class

Comment: `Class A = new A();` doesn't compile.

Comment: @tgdavies sorry it was a typo. the actual issue is still there.